# Ansible repeating roles

Tags: ansible

I use Ansible to manage some web- and database servers which run websites for multiple vhosts. For each website I need to assign a database role to the dbservers group and a website role to the webservers group. So my playbook looks something like this:

```
- hosts: dbservers
  roles: 
      - { role: database, vhost: 'host1.com', db: 'customdb' }
      - { role: database, vhost: 'other.com' }

- hosts: webservers
  roles: 
      - { role: website, vhost: 'host1.com', db: 'customdb' }
      - { role: website, vhost: 'other.com' }
```

This works well, but it is ugly as I have to repeat everything twice. This is especially error-prone when changing some parameters from the default values (like db on vhost host1.com in this example).

Is there a way to write this so I can have a single list of vhosts with all the required parameters and automatically add the different roles to the different host groups for each vhost entry?

Comment: Could you use `with_items` maybe?

Comment: I might be wrong, but if I understand it correctly with_items is not available for roles.

Answer (score 8):

the most obvious answer - use complex variables (dictionaries) to hold your values, and then pass entire variable:

```
- layouts:
  - layout1:
      vhost: host1.com
      db: customdb
  - layout2:
      vhost: other.com
```

then use those to pass over to roles:

```
- hosts: dbservers
  roles:
  - { role: database, layout: layouts.layout1 }
  - { role: database, layout: layouts.layout2 }

- hosts: webservers
  roles:
  - { role: webserver, layout: layouts.layout1 }
  - { role: webserver, layout: layouts.layout2 }
```

I've done this successfully in the past. To populate layouts you can use various techniques: combining "group_vars/all" with "vars_files" with "host_vars" etc.

Comment: This will help to make sure I don't accidentally give different parameters to the web servers and the database servers. But still has lots of repetition, is there a way to get rid of that?

Answer (score 5):

What I do is I create roles `apache`, which installs apache and does some configuration for all vhosts, `apache-vhost`, which installs a vhost, `host1-com`, and `other-com`. Then the playbook would be like this:

```
- hosts: host1-com-servers
  roles:
    - apache
    - host1-com

- hosts: other-com-servers
  roles:
    - apache
    - other-com
```

Now, `host1-com` will have this:

```
- meta:
  - dependencies:
    - role: apache-vhost
      server_name: host1.com
      server_aliases:
        - www.host1.com
      extras: |
        Alias /static /var/local/myapp/static
        <Location /static>
          Require all granted
        </Location>
        # Whatever else you want
      whatever_other_variables_apache-vhost_needs: XXX
```

(This is an implementation detail, but the `apache-vhost` role prepares some essential vhost configuration based on the variables passed to it, and also adds the `extras` variable as is inside the vhost configuration.)

Likewise for the databases, you can have a `postgresql` role, a `postgresql-database` role, and so on.

Answer (score 4):

Rather than group your hosts by function, you could group them by role and have Ansible run a given role on a host only if that host is found in the designated group for that role.

```
[role_db_customdb]
other.com

[role_db_otherdb]
host1.com

[role_website]
host1.com
other.com
```

You can even pass parameters to a role, as illustrated with the `db` parameter in the playbook below.

```
---
- hosts: all

  roles:
    - { role: database, db: 'customdb', when: inventory_hostname in groups.role_db_customdb }
    - { role: database, db: 'otherdb', when: inventory_hostname in groups.role_db_otherdb }
    - { role: website, when: inventory_hostname in groups.role_webservers }
```

Comment: I see where this would make sense to do this, but this doesn't help with my problem. Each web site (vhost) needs to be configured on each web server and a database on each database server. So "host1.com" is configured on web1, web2 and web3 and gets a database called "customdb" on the database servers db1 and db2.